# Assistance with parsing Json packet

Tags: json, python-2.7

All,

I have googled this to death but I can't figure out how to parse this type of JSON packet.

{

"recipients":[

"\"Name 1\" ",

"\"Name 2\" ",

"\"Name 3\" "

]

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

very simple, as my code:

import json

j = json.loads('{"recipients": ["Name 1", "Name 2","Name 3"] }')

print (j['recipients'])

=> ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3']

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Correct, I can output that list but how do I snag each item out of RECIPIENTS?

Comment: WAIT! I got it!

for k in participants['recipients']:
        print k